# How to set the parameter of the global planner in navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, planner, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

The global planner pkg provides few algorithms like A*, grid path and etc. My question is how I can set these methods? For example, for grid path method I need to set global planner parameter as "use_grid_path=True" but I do not know where and how I should set it? Do I set them as rosparam in launch file?

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239984/how-to-set-the-parameter-of-the-global-planner-in-navigation-stack/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Option A) Yes, in a launch file.

Option B) Command line using rosrun http://wiki.ros.org/rosbash#rosrun

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-07-21**:
Adding a good example for option (A): [turtlebot_navigation](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_navigation) @alireza_m See `launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml` and and `param/global_planner_params.yaml`